Protein structure prediction: levels of coarse-graining in deep learning approaches
I am researching the areas of protein structure prediction, protein + ligand pose prediction, and co-folding algos with deep learning. I am trying to map the current state of the art architectures used across those problem domains.
There seems to be two levels of coarse-graining used to represent the protein: residue level (alpha carbon) or all (heavy) atoms. I am trying to understand the advantages/disadvantages of the two methods.
Residue level representation offers clear computational advantages, but surely neglects important physics like side-chain orientation at the active site.
Many models seem to mix the two representations (my interpretation from papers):
DiffDock: residue level representation of protein, all atom for ligand (score model). All atom for protein and ligand (confidence model).
NeuralPlexer: starts with residue level protein representation, finishes with atomistic representation of protein + ligand.
RoseTTAFold All-Atom: residue level protein representation, all atom ligand graph.
Why do some architectures choose residue > all atom?

+1. Welcome to our community.
